# Select query not allowed duplicate record

Tags: apex, soql

I have Trigger,in Trigger I have one select query.That select query returns duplicate records.
My query is :

```
LIST<Company__c> li = LIST<Company__c>();
LIST<String> companynames= LIST<String>(); 
companynames.add('tempabc');
companynames.add('tempabc1');

li= [SELECT Id,Name FROM Company__c WHERE Name IN : companynames];
```

**Note :** The Company names come from dynamic list when the Trigger is fired as of now I am hard coded.

But Now I am getting the 3 records from the Company Object.
1).Name=tempabc
2).Name=tempabc
3).Name=tempabc1

I need to query the without duplicate records?
Please some one help me.

Best Regards,
Ramesh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't use `set` instead of `List` this will prevent entering same names.

```
Set<String> companynames=  new Set<String>(); 
companynames.add('tempabc');
companynames.add('tempabc1');

li= [SELECT Id,Name FROM Company__c WHERE Name IN : companynames];

// This will prevent entering same name records if soql return
Map<String, Company__c> uniqueNameRecords = new Map<String, Comapany__c>();
for(Company__c company : li)
{
   uniqueNameRecords.put(company.name, company); 
}
```

Comment: Can you explain how this will help or make a difference to "select query returns duplicate records" ?

Answer (score 3):

I have a feeling those records are not duplicates, but rather different records with the same name. I would output the `Id`s and verify against them.

Comment: I was going to answer the same, there is no way soql would return duplicates.

Comment: You are absolutely correct Mr Jessen Altman.Id are different but Names are same.

Comment: @Ramesh glad I could help

Comment: I would also recommend using a Set<Id> rather than a List. When you add these Ids to your set, please remember to check their sizes in case you are providing a mix of 18 and 15 character Ids.